# localStorage is not defined in Next.js and Redux

Tags: redux, next.js

im trying to set up shopping cart with redux in next.js.

i have this function :

```
const loadCartState = () => {
  const storedCartState = localStorage.getItem("cartState");
  return storedCartState ? JSON.parse(storedCartState) : undefined;
};
```

which i call here :

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(cartLocalStorageMiddleware),
  preloadedState: {
    cart: loadCartState(),
  },
});
```

now everthing works great but when i refresh i get the localStorage is not defined error,
i tried this :

```
const loadCartState = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage) {
    const storedCartState = localStorage.getItem("cartState");
    return storedCartState ? JSON.parse(storedCartState) : undefined;
  }
};
```

and now the not defined error is gone but when there is items in my cart and i refresh i get a hydration error.

Comment: are you sure, this code is running on the client side (ie in the browser) and not on the backend?

Comment: yeah its on client side

Comment: the fact, that accessing `localStorage` results in an error suggests otherwise ...